# How to add a custom link to product page magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, product-attribute, custom-options, custom-button

I want to add custom link in More Information tab.
See attached screenshot:

I want to give a link instead of text

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an Attribute in admin with text type say `external_link`
- Add phtml at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="external.link" template="Magento_Catalog::externallink.phtml"/>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create phtml and get attribute value:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/externallink.phtml

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if($link = $product->getExternalLink()){ ?>
    <div class="link">
        <a href="<?= $link; ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Link text')) ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: Hi pawan, link should be different for all products.

Comment: Yes, that's why we created an attribute so you can add different link to each product!

Comment: Can we display same Custom link in more information tab.

Comment: Yes, you need to set Attribute `Yes` for `Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront` in `Storefront Properties` tab

Comment: Thank you so much. code is working but can we display button instead of URL in more information tab.

Comment: If you want to add link in more information tab, you need to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml` and need to add if else condition

Comment: Can you guide me please how can I add if else comdition?

Comment: Answer added here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318392/move-custom-product-in-more-information-tab/318437#318437 please check

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to do the following things.

1. first create one product attribute where you mention this link of third party.
2. Now create one custom extension and create custom phtml file and call the file on product page on specific by using reference block.
3. Now in that phtml file, fetch that product attribute value and show to customer.

Comment: Hi Dhiren, Can we give  a link instead of text in More Information tab.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding the attribute then importing via csv with text similar to the following

```
'<a href='https://pirate.black/' target='_blank'>https://pirate.black//</a>
```

It will also work if directly entered in the new product attribute.