# Move custom product in More Information Tab

Tags: product, layout, product-attribute, xml, magento2.3.1

I want to move product attributes inside the more Information tab.

[image]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your attribute code is `external_link`

Now copy:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

Now we will add an if condition for `external_link` code and add `a` tag like:

```
<?php if($_data['code']=='external_link') { ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml("Manufacturer Webpage") ?></th>
            <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_data['label']) ?>"><a href="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>">More Detail</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } else{?>
    <tr>
        .... code for other attribute
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

full file code would be:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()) :?>
    <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('More Information')) ?></caption>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data) :?>
                <?php if($_data['code']=='external_link') { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml("Manufacturer Webpage") ?></th>
                        <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_data['label']) ?>"><a href="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>">More Detail</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } else{?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
                    <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_data['label']) ?>"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: I added full file code in attributes.phrml but not working.

Comment: did you changed attribute code ?

Comment: Yes, only need to change attribute code.

Comment: if you changed attribute code, make sure your you template override working. for test add code to core file OR Add additional class to any div and check it.

Comment: Thank you so much.